# Report all possible combinations of columns

Tags: mysql, excel, bash, combinations, summary

I have a question regarding combinations generally, but in a fairly complex situation which I have not yet been able to find any help on. I am trying to find a way to report all possible combinations of *columns* in a dataset.

The data report on a literature survey of land change, and indicate which proximate and underlying drivers are reported in each article. Thus, the rows indicate individual articles, and the columns all proximate and underlying drivers. There are six types of proximate drivers and five types of underlying drivers. For each article, a 1 is placed in the columns of the drivers identified in that article, and a 0 in the columns of the drivers that are not. The table looks roughly like so:

```
key | d1 | d2 |...| d6 | i1 |...| i5 |
--------------------------------------
A1  | 1  | 0  |...| 1  | 1  |...| 0  |
A2  | 0  | 1  |...| 0  | 0  |...| 1  |
```

Where article A1 identifies d1 and d6 as direct drivers and i1 as an indirect driver, etc.

What I would like to do is find out the number of articles reporting each of all possible combinations of direct drivers, indirect drivers, and direct and indirect drivers. So, for instance, how many articles identify d1, d2, and i1; how many identify d1, d2, and i2; and so on? My students have the table in an Excel file, and I was thinking that perhaps Calc or Base might have a function to automate the process. Does anyone have an idea as to how I could do this?

Thank you!

Comment: so you want to identify all 2^11 combinations and count how many of each there are? that's 2048 different combinations.

Comment: That's why I was hoping to simplify the process. The idea is to identify which combinations of drivers occur most frequently in the literature.

Comment: Combine the drivers into a conditional string using a little UDF(or concatenate the binary digits). Then use a pivot table to count how many of each combination string.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and went with a brute-force approach. I exported the table to text and pulled it into MySQL, then used a bash script to iterate through the options. In case anyone else has a similar issue, here is the bash script:

```
    # Generate array containing factors
faclis1=( d_inf d_com d_inm d_ind d_agr d_bos i_dem i_eco i_tec i_pol i_cul );
#faclis=( "d_inf" "d_com" "d_inm" );
a=0
#echo ${faclis[@]};


# Remove output file if exists
if [ -e permcounts.txt ];
    then
    rm permcounts.txt;
    fi;

# Cycle through list of factors
for f1 in ${faclis1[@]};
do
# only proceed if factor not null
if [ ${f1} ];
then
# print remaining array just to be sure
echo "factor list is ${faclis1[@]}";
#echo ${faclis[@]};
echo "Now on factor ${f1}";
echo "FACTOR ${f1}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;
# create sub array without current factor, 2 factors
faclis2=( ${faclis1[@]/${f1}/} );
#set sub-counter
b=0
#echo "${faclis2[@]}";
# loop through sub array, two factors
for f2 in ${faclis2[@]};
do
if [ ${f2} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f2}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis3=( ${faclis2[@]//${f2}} );
c=0
#echo "${faclis3[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f3 in ${faclis3[@]};
do
if [ ${f3} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f3}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f3}" ];

then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis4=( ${faclis3[@]//${f3}} );
d=0
#echo "${faclis4[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f4 in ${faclis4[@]};
do
if [ ${f4} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f4}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f4}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f4}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis5=( ${faclis4[@]//${f4}} );
e=0
#echo "${faclis5[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f5 in ${faclis5[@]};
do
if [ ${f5} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f5}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f5}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f5}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f5}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis6=( ${faclis5[@]//${f5}} );
f=0
#echo "${faclis6[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f6 in ${faclis6[@]};
do
if [ ${f6} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f6}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f6}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f6}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f6}" ] && \
[ "${f5}" != "${f6}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5} \
AND ${f6}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1 and \
${f6} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis7=( ${faclis6[@]//${f6}} );
g=0
#echo "${faclis7[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f7 in ${faclis7[@]};
do
if [ ${f7} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f7}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f7}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f7}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f7}" ] && \
[ "${f5}" != "${f7}" ] && \
[ "${f6}" != "${f7}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5} \
AND ${f6} \
AND ${f7}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1 and \
${f6} = 1 and \
${f7} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis8=( ${faclis7[@]//${f7}} );
h=0
#echo "${faclis8[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f8 in ${faclis8[@]};
do
if [ ${f8} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f8}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f8}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f8}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f8}" ] && \
[ "${f5}" != "${f8}" ] && \
[ "${f6}" != "${f8}" ] && \
[ "${f7}" != "${f8}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5} \
AND ${f6} \
AND ${f7} \
AND ${f8}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1 and \
${f6} = 1 and \
${f7} = 1 and \
${f8} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis9=( ${faclis8[@]//${f8}} );
i=0
#echo "${faclis9[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f9 in ${faclis9[@]};
do
if [ ${f9} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f5}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f6}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f7}" != "${f9}" ] && \
[ "${f8}" != "${f9}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5} \
AND ${f6} \
AND ${f7} \
AND ${f8} \
AND ${f9}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1 and \
${f6} = 1 and \
${f7} = 1 and \
${f8} = 1 and \
${f9} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis10=( ${faclis9[@]//${f9}} );
j=0
#echo "${faclis10[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f10 in ${faclis10[@]};
do
if [ ${f10} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f5}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f6}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f7}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f8}" != "${f10}" ] && \
[ "${f9}" != "${f10}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5} \
AND ${f6} \
AND ${f7} \
AND ${f8} \
AND ${f9} \
AND ${f10}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1 and \
${f6} = 1 and \
${f7} = 1 and \
${f8} = 1 and \
${f9} = 1 and \
${f10} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

# next sub-array
faclis11=( ${faclis10[@]//${f10}} );
k=0
#echo "${faclis11[@]}";
# loop through sub-array
for f11 in ${faclis11[@]};
do
if [ ${f11} ] && \
[ "${f1}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f2}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f3}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f4}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f5}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f6}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f7}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f8}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f9}" != "${f11}" ] && \
[ "${f10}" != "${f11}" ];
then
echo "FACTOR ${f1} \
AND ${f2} \
AND ${f3} \
AND ${f4} \
AND ${f5} \
AND ${f6} \
AND ${f7} \
AND ${f8} \
AND ${f9} \
AND ${f10} \
AND ${f11}" >> permcounts.txt;
mysql -u harvey -pdavid -e "select count(clave) from genfact where \
${f1} = 1 and \
${f2} = 1 and \
${f3} = 1 and \
${f4} = 1 and \
${f5} = 1 and \
${f6} = 1 and \
${f7} = 1 and \
${f8} = 1 and \
${f9} = 1 and \
${f10} = 1 and \
${f11} = 1;" metamorelia >> permcounts.txt;

unset faclis11[k];
k=$((${k} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis10[j];
j=$((${j} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis9[i];
i=$((${i} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis8[h];
h=$((${h} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis7[g];
g=$((${g} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis6[f];
f=$((${f} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis5[e];
e=$((${e} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis4[d];
d=$((${d} + 1));
fi;
done;
unset faclis3[c];
c=$((${c} + 1));
fi;
done;
# Remove analyzed factors from vector
unset faclis2[b];
b=$((${b} + 1));
fi;
done;
# remove nth item from array (progressively remove one item)
unset faclis1[a];
# increment n for next round
a=$((${a} + 1));
echo ${n};
fi;
done;
```

This script is somewhat inefficient in that I think I included a lot of unnecessary operations, but it got the job done. (I think it did. My students will have to navigate the output file to make sure that everything is there.)